# Pass a database name to a stored procedure and use this variable name in the code

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I have been researching and don't see my exact situation. I have a SQL Server stored procedure that references a database with a few lookup tables. The procedure is run from our "main database" and using fully qualified names (Db name, schema, table name) joins to the lookup tables in the lookup database. Every so often we will get an updated version of these lookup values. The new values will be placed into a new database with matching names from prior versions. The database names can change slightly i.e. `LookupDB_1` then `LookupDB_2`. Can I create and pass a variable called `LookupDB_2` when I get the update and have `LookupDB_2` "point" to the right lookup tables in my coding? There are multiple references to the lookup DB in the code. This would be better than later users doing a find and replace on the lookup database name and altering the procedure.

Example code:

```
SELECT ColumnNames  
FROM dbo.MainTable m
LEFT JOIN LookupDB_1.dbo.LookupTableName l      -- lookup database name changes 
  ON m.id = l.lookupid
```

Thanks.

Comment: Its really unclear what you are trying to do... actual sample data to illustrate would really help. However best guess is you need some dynamic SQL - for which there are loads of resources available.

Comment: You could [create synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) pointing to these objects and reference the synonyms in the code - then you just need to update the synonyms when you want to start referencing the new DB - assuming the switch is something you just want to do globally

Comment: Here is an example:

select fieldnames  
FROM dbo.MainTable m
LEFT JOIN LookupDB_1.dbo.LookupTableName l  -- lookup database name changes 
  ON m.id = l.lookupid 

I didn't think dynamic sql was realistic with the large amount of code I have. The lookup database name is mentioned in a few places in the script. Thanks

Comment: In short, this is completely backwards. You should not be creating a newly named table  (let alone database!!!) every time you import new lookups. You should be merging / replacing data in an existing table. You should also avoid doing cross database joins beacause this will impede any eventual migration to Azure SQL. It sounds like the data engineering team don't know what they are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create views of the lookup tables in another database and use them in your stored procedure instead of direct references to the lookup database. Then create a Stored procedure with dynamic SQL to Alter the views when the lookup database changes. This would be simpler to maintain because it would be entirely transparent in any object that referred to the lookups and would also perform better than having to use dynamic SQL throughout your database.

Comment: I have never thought of this and will try it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Synonyms seem a simpler solution though

Comment: Using Views or Synonyms would be much the same. A synonym would be required for each table because a database cannot be referred to with a synonym. The synonyms would also need to be updated with dynamic SQL in a Stored Procedure when the lookup database changed. The main advantage of a Synonym would be it could have a shorter name but maybe it would be faster too?

Nick's comment is on the money though. The whole situation should be avoided.

Comment: Thank you Galaxiom. I presented the use of views in another database with updates when new databases were added to point to the new lookup tables to my manager. I offered this as Option no 2. I suggested the best option be to simply update the current lookup tables repeatedly with some type of identifier to filter on for each update. Thanks everyone!